# Upload while switching pages (C# jQuery)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

i'm searching for a way to upload huge files with jQuery and C#/VB.net (ASP).

I want to open an uploadform, select a file and upload it. After firing the upload (submit) it must be possible to leave the page with the upload form, and switching to another page within the same domain (Fire & Forget).

Can this be realized with jQuery and C# / VB.Net. On which Keywords i have to look to find a solution to get this working or is this impossible ?

Greetings
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You can use an async upload like following and then write a code to redirect a page.

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2011/12/async-file-upload-with-jquery-and.html

at the end of process request method write following code.

```
context.Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx");
```